# C# Merge 2 streams into one

Tags: c#, stream

I have 2 streams.

```
Stream stream1 
Stream stream2
```

How do I merge these 2 streams into one?

Clarification:

- The streams are Crystal Report outputs.  I want to be able to append the output of 2 or more Crystal reports.  No external libraries please.
- Net 4.0
- Memory Stream

Complete code:

```
// Create stream from crytal report run
        Stream stream = crystalReportUtilities.RunCrystalReport(...
        Stream stream2 = crystalReportUtilities.RunCrystalReport(...

        return File(stream, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: Obligatory: "Don't cross the streams!"

Comment: Other than *"merging them into one"* what are you trying to do with them? Do you need to just read the first and append the result of reading the second? In this case you'll need to clarify **merge** I think.

Comment: are you perhaps trying to merge 2 files into one..?

Comment: define "merge" in this context.  There are probably a dozen different ways you could interpret that.

Comment: Do you mean stream2 appended to the end of stream1 yields stream3? Also, what type of stream and version of .NET? You can do this in a non-specific manner, but some stream derivatives implement methods that make this trivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your streams are binary streams representing a PDF, there is no existing functionality in the .Net API to merge two PDFs. A such, you will have to either write your own or use an external library (we use [PdfSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/), it works pretty well).